# js babel return await is not working

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, async-await, babeljs

I'm trying to return data from an async function to a non async function it always returns a promise here is my code

```
static async getById(id){
    const db = await mongodb;
    const mongoId = new ObjectID(id);
    return await db.collection(Restaurant.collectionName).findOne({_id:mongoId});
  }
const obj = Restaurant.getById(data);//called in a non async function so i cannot use await 
        return new Restaurant(obj);
```

as mentioned in the comment i cannot use await on the async function call so i need the async function getById to wait for the data before returning
what should i do

Answer (score 1):

> i cannot use await on the async function call so i need the async function getById to wait for the data before returning

That's not what `async function`s do. As the name says, they are *asynchronous*, and they do return a promise for their result. They do not block and return synchronously. You have to wait, there's no way around it. Make the function with the calls `async` as well.

Comment: well the function that calls it is the constructor of a class which cannot be set as async that's why i was looking for a work around ... what i did is that i made a factory function that creates new instances of that class and set it as async

Comment: @AmgadSerry Yes, [constructors shouldn't call async functions](http://stackoverflow.com/q/24398699/1048572) at all

Comment: that is true it's much more cleaner to have an async factory function that actually instantiate objects of the class based on the given data